# Array of numbers in a matrix (2x1) without changing its shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I made an array of shape = [2,1] and I assigned the array with one-dimensional array of shape [3,1]. The problem occurring is that the array shape is changed from [2,1] to [2,1,3]. How can I make compiler understand that one dimensional array should be considered as a single element

> > > k = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
> > >
> > > a = np.zeros(shape = [2,1], dtype = float)
> > >
> > > a = np.array([[k[0]],[k[1]]])
> > >
> > > a.shape

(2, 1, 3)

> > > a = np.array([[np.asarray(k[0])],[np.asarray(k[1])]])
> > >
> > > a.shape

(2, 1, 3)

Comment: You aren't changing the shape of `a`.  You are creating new arrays, and assigning them to the variable `a`.  The initial `np.zeros` has nothing to do with following array creations.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you actually want a 2D array whose elements are 1D arrays? That's an odd thing to do, but if you do want to do it, clearly the dtype of the 2D array can't be float, because a 1D array is not a float.

Comment: Yeah I know, but how can i insert an array in matrix as a single element. I know it can be done because in some cases it worked. But when I assign an array by giving a  specific index to an array(which contains list of arrays) like in the above example k[0][0] it doesnt work

Comment: `numpy` array are fix-sized, homogeneously typed, true multi-dimensional arrays. You generally do not put numpy arrays as an element of another numpy array. That necessitates an `object` dtype, which defeats the *whole purpose* of `numpy`, so just use a normal `list` if you want to do soething like this.

Comment: List usage changes the dimension too. I agree with you on the dtype object thing but still it should work right?
This is the case where it worked
>>> a = np.array([[np.asarray([1,2,3]),np.asarray([5,6])]])
>>> a
array([[array([1, 2, 3]), array([5, 6])]], dtype=object)
>>> a.shape
(1, 2)


So i changed my dtype from float to object but still the dimension changes.

Comment: I got (2,1) shape for your examples, with elements 1 and 4.

Comment: There maybe a mistake in my question. a value will be a = np.array([[k[0]],[k[1]]])

Comment: That last expression makes a new array.  It doesn't insert anything into the previously defined `a`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: k = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Constructing an array from the elements of `k`:

```
In [2]: a = np.array([[k[0]],[k[1]]])
In [3]: a
Out[3]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3]],

       [[4, 5, 6]]])
In [4]: a.shape
Out[4]: (2, 1, 3)
```

If we take off a layer of []:

```
In [7]: a = np.array([k[0],k[1]])
In [8]: a
Out[8]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In [9]: a.shape
Out[9]: (2, 3)
```

We can initialize an object dtype array and fill it with values from `k`:

```
In [10]: a =np.empty(2, object)
In [11]: a
Out[11]: array([None, None], dtype=object)
In [12]: a[:] = k
In [13]: a
Out[13]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)
In [14]: a.shape
Out[14]: (2,)
```

Here the `a[:]=k` assignment worked fine; sometimes we get shape/broadcasting errors and may have to assign element by element.

Such as with:

```
In [15]: a =np.empty((2,1), object)
In [16]: a[:] = k
...
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 3 to array axis with dimension 1

In [17]: a[:,0] = k     # the 1d assignment as before
In [18]: a
Out[18]: 
array([[list([1, 2, 3])],
       [list([4, 5, 6])]], dtype=object)
```

Note, we have to use indexed assignment to change values of an existing array.  `a = ...` assigns a new array to the variable; it does not modify an existing one.